# Does nesting NIntegrate inside ParallelMap hinder NIntegrate's built-in parallel execution?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, parallelization

I have a function `fun[a_,b_]` and I want to `NIntegrate` that function with respect to `a` for each of about 8 values of `b` that are stored in `bValList`. I am considering using

```
ParallelMap[ 
  NIntegrate[fun[a,#],{a,0,1}]&,
  bValList]
```

I've read that `NIntegrate` does some things in parallel already. Assuming I have sufficiently many kernels available, would nesting `NIntegrate` inside `ParallelMap` prevent `NIntegrate` from its usual automatic parallel execution?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `NIntegrate`'s parallel capabilities?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I mentioned that in multiple answers. I noticed it when looking at CPU usage while running a long integration. You can try it.

Comment: For example, try `Do[
 NIntegrate[1/x Cos[Log[x]/x], {x, 0, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
  MaxRecursion -> 30],
 {100}
 ]` and watch the CPU usage.  The answer is the same to the OP.  You can try it on your own.

Comment: Please do not accept my answer for now. I hope someone will explain the strange results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NIntegrate`'s parallel capabilities are not documented.  It is something I noticed by chance.  This means that you should experiment to try to get an answer to your question (and keep in mind that not all integrals may behave the same).

For example,

```
int[] := NIntegrate[1/x Cos[Log[x]/x], {x, 0, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, MaxRecursion -> 30]

Do[int[], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {13.0918, Null} *)
```

During this computation I can see 50% CPU usage on a 4-core, 8-thread CPU.  Taking the CPU's "hyperthreading" capabilities into account, this is essentially full utilization of all 4 cores.

Let us now run the same calculation in a *single* subkernel, and observe the CPU usage again.

```
LaunchKernels[]
(* {"KernelObject"[1, "local"], "KernelObject"[2, "local"], 
 "KernelObject"[3, "local"], "KernelObject"[4, "local"]} *)

k = First[%]
(* "KernelObject"[1, "local"] *)

DistributeDefinitions[int]
(* int *)

ParallelEvaluate[Do[int[], {100}], k] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {12.9261, Null} *)
```

This time I see that only a single core is being used.  This indicates that NIntegrate won't work in parallel on a subkernel.  However, the timing for the calculation is the same!  I do not know why.

Let us now try to run the same `Do` in parallel, using all four subkernels at the same time.

```
ParallelDo[int[], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.57534, Null} *)
```

I see full CPU utilization again, and now the timing is only about 1/4 of the original.

So it seems that `NIntegrate` does use parallelization very efficiently, and it is still worth running it in an explicit parallel loop (like `ParallelDo`).

I do not understand why this is.  Further investigation would be useful, but I am going to stop here.

Comment: I observe the same with your examples using *Mathematica* 11.1.1. But when I run them in version 8.0.4 I get the same timings **but** your first example (evaluation in the master kernel) runs only in **one** core! So "parallelization" in the master kernel of version 11.1.1 is very suspicious: it doesn't give an advantage in timing but seem to take all CPU cores for nothing!

Comment: @Szabolcs It may be related to similar restrictions on the parallelization of `LinearSolve`/LAPACK, which I assume `"LevinRule"` uses in your example. I do not know the internals and cannot really say how wild this guess is.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It certainly is (e.g. MKLThreadNumber system option).  What's weird here is that when NIntegrate uses all 4 cores, it still takes just as much time as when it uses only one core.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is indeed MKLThreadNumber. The problem can be reproduced like this too: 1. check that MKLThreadNumber is 4 at startup, time NIntegrate (13 s).  2. set it to 1, check that NIntegrate uses only one core, but notice that it still takes 13 seconds.  BTW this might not happen with all integrands.

Comment: Another wild guess: Cost of overhead = savings of parallelization.  The default Levin system is 23 x 23, which size `LinearSolve` does not seem to parallelize. With `Method -> {"LevinRule", "Points" -> 256}`, which yields a 513 x 513 system, I see a 33% savings of `Do[int[], {10}]` over `ParallelEvaluate[..]` (134 vs 200 sec.).  I suspect there's other parallelization going on, too, which makes guesswork difficult. -- Concerning the thread number, one can verify it is limited for subkernels with `ParallelEvaluate[SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber"]]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs You asked me to comment on this, but I have to say I am not familiar with the current `NIntegrate` set-up for parallel computations. (If any.) My guess is that the way `NIntegrate` treats lists of integrands is used to parallelize the computations. (By some sort of default, non-`NIntegrate` specific way.) Very often symbolic pre-processing would produce a list of integration regions or stand-alone integrals. This opens the possibility for parallel computations too.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the testing approaches. When I have a moment, I'll explore them for my particular integrand.

Comment: @FalafelPita I think the best answer is what I said in my comment: test for yourself. Parallelization always has some overhead. Sometimes that overhead negates all speedups.  In this case the question is: which method will have the smaller overhead? I don't have a good insight into that so I would just benchmark for myself, keeping in mind that the results will be different for different problems (as Michael showed)